# How to render list of mixed objects and array in product listing page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular and really excited by its capabilities. As practice, I'm developing a "View all products" list that will display all products in my database.

At the moment, the server returns a JSON response that looks like the following, which is a list of all the products (or "devices"):

```
{
  "devices": [
    {
      "productId": "prod12345",
      "name": "Device One",
      "manufacturer": "Manufacturer One",
      "os": "Android",
      "images_small": "photo.jpg",
      "images_medium": "photo.jpg",
      "images_large": "photo.jpg",
      "memory_internal": "128MB",
      "groupName": "",
      "color": "green",
    },
    {
      "productId": "prod23456",
      "name": "Device Two",
      "manufacturer": "Manufacturer Two",
      "os": "Android",
      "images_small": "photo.jpg",
      "images_medium": "photo.jpg",
      "images_large": "photo.jpg",
      "memory_internal": "128MB",
      "groupName": "",
      "color": "yellow",
    },
    {
      "productId": "prod34567",
      "name": "Device Three",
      "manufacturer": "Manufacturer Three",
      "os": "iOS",
      "images_small": "photo.jpg",
      "images_medium": "photo.jpg",
      "images_large": "photo.jpg",
      "memory_internal": "128 MB",
      "groupName": "groupOne",
      "color": "blue",
    },
    {
      "productId": "prod34568",
      "name": "Device Three",
      "manufacturer": "Manufacturer Three",
      "os": "iOS",
      "images_small": "photo.jpg",
      "images_medium": "photo.jpg",
      "images_large": "photo.jpg",
      "memory_internal": "256 MB",
      "groupName": "groupOne",
      "color": "blue",
    },
}
```

As you can see from the above, it would be pretty easy to just "ng-repeat" through all the products, however some of the products are actually part of a "group" or "family" of devices and should only warrant a single listing (with color and memory option dropdowns).

As such, I refactored the JSON response to be closer to this, where grouped products are nested in an array:

```
{
  "devices": [
    {
      "productId": "prod12345",
      "name": "Device One",
      "manufacturer": "Manufacturer One",
      "os": "Android",
      "images_small": "photo.jpg",
      "images_medium": "photo.jpg",
      "images_large": "photo.jpg",
      "memory_internal": "260 MB",
      "groupName": "",
      "color": "green",
    },
    {
      "productId": "prod23456",
      "name": "Device Two",
      "manufacturer": "Manufacturer Two",
      "os": "Android",
      "images_small": "photo.jpg",
      "images_medium": "photo.jpg",
      "images_large": "photo.jpg",
      "memory_internal": "260 MB",
      "groupName": "",
      "color": "yellow",
    },
    [
        {
            "productId": "prod34567",
            "name": "Device Three",
            "manufacturer": "Manufacturer Three",
            "os": "iOS",
            "images_small": "photo.jpg",
            "images_medium": "photo.jpg",
            "images_large": "photo.jpg",
            "memory_internal": "128 MB",
            "groupName": "groupOne",
            "color": "blue",
        },
        {
            "productId": "prod34568",
            "name": "Device Three",
            "manufacturer": "Manufacturer Three",
            "os": "iOS",
            "images_small": "photo.jpg",
            "images_medium": "photo.jpg",
            "images_large": "photo.jpg",
            "memory_internal": "256 MB",
            "groupName": "groupOne",
            "color": "orange",
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "productId": "prod456789",
            "name": "Device Four",
            "manufacturer": "Manufacturer Four",
            "os": "iOS",
            "images_small": "photo.jpg",
            "images_medium": "photo.jpg",
            "images_large": "photo.jpg",
            "memory_internal": "128 MB",
            "groupName": "groupTwo",
            "color": "blue",
        },
        {
            "productId": "prod456781",
            "name": "Device Four",
            "manufacturer": "Manufacturer Four",
            "os": "iOS",
            "images_small": "photo.jpg",
            "images_medium": "photo.jpg",
            "images_large": "photo.jpg",
            "memory_internal": "128 MB",
            "groupName": "groupTwo",
            "color": "yellow",
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, when I use ng-repeat, I do a secondary check for the type before deciding what to display:

```
<ul class="phone__list">
        <li ng-repeat="(key, range) in groupedDevices" class="phone">
            <div ng-switch="getTypeOf(range)">
                <div ng-switch-when="object">
                    <div class="phone__display-name">
                        <span ng-bind-html="range.manufacturer"></span>
                        <span ng-bind-html="range.name"></span>
                    </div>
                    <img src="{{ range.images_medium }}" alt="{{ range.name }}"/>
                </div>
                <div ng-switch-when="array">
                    <div class="phone__display-name">
                        <span ng-bind-html="range[0].manufacturer"></span>
                        <span ng-bind-html="range[0].name"></span>
                        <img src="{{ range[0].images_medium }}" alt="{{ range[0].name }}"/>
                        <select ng-model="orderProp" ng-options="device.colorValue for device in range | unique:'colorValue'"></select>
                        <select ng-model="orderProp" ng-options="device.memory_internal for device in range | unique:'memory_internal'"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

And my javascript:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.phones.all', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.filters'])

.filter('debug', function() {
    return function(input) {
        if (input === '') return 'empty string';
        return input ? input : ('' + input);
    };
})

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/phones', {
    templateUrl: 'views/phones/all.html',
    controller: 'GroupedPhonesController'
    });
}])

.factory('phonesFactory', function($http){

    return {
        getCompressedPhones: function() {
            //return the promise directly.
            return $http.get('http://localhost:8888/api/phones/compressed')
                .then(function(result) {
                    //resolve the promise as the data
                    console.log(result.data);
                    return result.data;
                });
        }
    };

})

.controller('GroupedPhonesController', function($scope, phonesFactory) {

    $scope.groupedDevices = {};

    init();

    function init() {

        phonesFactory.getCompressedPhones().then(function(groupedDevices) {
            $scope.groupedDevices = groupedDevices;
        });

    }

    $scope.getTypeOf = function(value) {
        if(value === null) {
            return "null";
        }
        if(Array.isArray(value)) {
            return "array";
        }
        return typeof value;
    };

});
```

So, as you can see - I'm trying to setup my template to accommodate the two different types of products (objects and arrays) but I feel as if I'm pigeon holing myself to a point where I won't be able to have filter functionality on the list as a whole. My question - is this the right approach? How would you best render a list of products knowing that some of them are in "families" and the additional options (internal memory and color) need to be displayed underneath the devices that have additional options?

Comment: you can use this notation instead of ng-bind-html directive  <span>{{range.manufacturer}}</span>

Comment: i'd suggest to create some product-directive and run it as ng-repeat through each item if its length > 0. otherway output item itself

Comment: @KaterinaTort I was using html in my json (like &trade; &copy;)and couldn't parse it any other way and great idea on the directives. I haven't fully had my aha moment with angular but I reason to believe that's a good approach.